# Is this function convex ? (Riemannian geometry)

Tags: convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

Let $f:M\to\mathbb R$ be a geodesically convex function on a Riemannian manifold $M$, assumed to have nonpositive sectional curvature.

Fix $x_0\in M$ and let $g:T_{x_0}M\to\mathbb R$ the map defined by $g(u)=f(\exp_{x_0}(u))$.

Is $g$ convex ?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Straight line in tangent space (not through 0) can differ a lot from a geodesic.

Comment: @user10354138 I agree with that, but it does not necessarily contradict the convexity of $g$.

Comment: Assuming smoothness, then $f$ is geodesically convex iff $\operatorname{Hess}f=\nabla\operatorname{grad}f=(\partial_{ij}f-\Gamma^k_{ij}\partial_k f)$ is psd and $g$ is convex iff $(\partial_{ij}f)$ is psd.  That should give you indications on how to find a counterexample.

Comment: Would you be willing to give details? For the second "iff", when I try to make the computation, it seems that Jacobi fields and curvature necessarily show up.